# Linked list and Struct on C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am trying to make an inventory program with using linked list but I have a problem when I want to show the list of data that i've input.
this is the code to input the data :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct t_barang
{
   char kode[9];
   char nama[30];
   int  harga;
   int  stok;
};

struct l_barang
{
   struct t_barang item;
   struct l_barang *next;
};

int main(){
    typedef struct l_barang *p_barang;
    struct l_barang *head;
    head=NULL;
    int jumlah=0;
    do{
        printf("Input Jumlah barang = ");
        scanf("%d", &jumlah);
        if(jumlah == 0)
            break;
        else{
            struct l_barang *baru = (struct l_barang*) malloc(sizeof(struct l_barang));
            printf("Input Kode barang = ");
            scanf("%s", &(baru->item).kode);
            printf("Input nama barang = ");
            scanf("%s", &(baru->item).nama);
            printf("Input harga barang = ");
            scanf("%d", &(baru->item).harga);
            baru->item.stok=jumlah;
            if(head == NULL){
                baru->next=NULL;
                    head=baru;}
            else{
                struct l_barang *tail;
                    tail=head;
                        while(tail->next != NULL){
                tail->next=NULL;
                tail = baru;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while(jumlah != 0);
```

and this is the code I use to show the data :

```
p_barang tampil = head;
    while(tampil){
        printf("%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\n",tampil->item.stok, tampil->item.kode, tampil->item.nama, tampil->item.harga);
    tampil=tampil->next;}
```

thank you!

Comment: But what's the problem? Please don't make/expect folks to read your code, debug it, and report the solution.

Comment: the problem is, the thing that showed when i've input the data only  the first data that I input, it can't shows the second data and the rest of it.

Comment: It's almost impossible to find any linked-list question where any debugging has been done.  It seems to be some sort of unwritten law that linked-list devlopers cannot debug and are driven to dump their code on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may come from here :

```
            tail=head;
            while(tail->next != NULL){
              tail->next=NULL;
              tail = baru;
            }
```

If `tail->next` is not NULL, set it to NULL,then change `tail`: this will trigger memory leakage and other problems...

The usual way is :

```
            tail=head;
            while(tail->next != NULL){
              tail=tail->next;
            }
            //tail is now the end of the list

            tail->next = baru;
            baru->next=NULL;
            //now, baru is the end of the list
```